# Is it possible to autogenerate Java class from DTD?

Tags: java, xml, dtd-parsing

I have DTD files of web service, now I need to map database to this web services and I need Java classes to create my entities. But doing this manually from DTD files would be very hard and long process. Is there any tools for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it a job for [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/) ?

Comment: +1, You can use the -dtd flag on the Metro JAXB XJC tool to generate Java classes from a DTD.

Answer (score 3):

xjc -dtd -d generatedsrc -p com.examples log4j.dtd

will generate the classes in directory generatedsrc and the package used will be com.examples.

you can find more information here:
http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/7622

Answer (score 0):

The problem is usually more than entity binding however. What about the transport or representing the services themselves? My preference depends on the 'flavor': for SOAP, I'd use the Axis Ant/Maven tasks or the Eclipse web service tools. REST, I wouldn't go past Jersey.